# RAID not working on HP Pavilion m7690y

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, raid

I have an elderly HP Pavilion m7690y running 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 which stopped booting. There are 2 300 GB SATA hard drives set up as a RAID0. While there is little of importance on the system, I would like to see if I can recover some pictures and other files before giving up and installing a fresh Linux OS. The Intel pre-boot RAID software reports a normal status (see image) [Photo of pre-boot Intel Raid Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvuVV.jpg)

However, the computer won't boot, except by using a liveCD copy of Ubuntu 16.04. Once booted, I can open a terminal window, run fdisk and the RAID sort of shows up.

Output from fdisk:

Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc2120895

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    1499135    1497088   731M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1501182 1250275327 1248774146 595.5G  5 Extended

Disk /dev/sdb: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_ecffbagjfc_Volume0: 596.2 GiB, 640141230080 bytes, 1250275840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc2120895

Device                                   Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/isw_ecffbagjfc_Volume0-part1         2048    1499135    1497088   731M 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/isw_ecffbagjfc_Volume0-part2      1501182 1250275327 1248774146 595.5G  5 Extende
/dev/mapper/isw_ecffbagjfc_Volume0-part5      1501184 1250275327 1248774144 595.5G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?